# Fine uploader in row of Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, fine-uploader

I am using Kendo() grid in my application which has binding with an model. I want to provide Upload control in Grid against each row.

Can i use "fine uploader third party control" for the same?

If yes, please let me know how to utilize "fine uploader third party control" in grid and call Action event on the same once the file is selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach demonstrates in this code library [here](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/upload/upload-in-grid-popup-editor.aspx).